# How to permanently finetune Syndaemon on 15.04?

Tags: touchpad, 15.04, autostart

I am using the HP Envy x360 15'. Everything works fine but it has an unusually large touchpad (for better Windows 8 usability). Every time I am typing I accidentally am hitting the touchpad and the mouse pointer jumps somewhere else creating chaos during typing.

The solution is to install `Touchpad-indicator` (as described [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/02/touchpad-indicator-now-automatically.html)) and set the *Disable touchpad on typing* -option. As far as I understand this uses `Sysdaemon` which is installed with any Ubuntu installation.

The problem is however that the *seconds to wait after the last key press before enabling the touchpad* -setting can only be set to 1 or 2 seconds. So far so good, but after using the 1 second setting for days now I have the feeling that my finger falls off as this setting is way too long to be practically usable when working with text.

You can fine-tune `Sysdaemon` as described [here](http://ubuntuwiki.net/index.php/Touchpad,_disabling_while_typing). For me, the command `syndaemon -i 0.3 -d -K` works best, but it does not autostart when I create an entry in Startup Applications. Is there any way to finetune `sysdaemon` in 15.04 and make it autostart?

Comment: You have a reputation score of 216, change the layout of your question plz =)

Comment: @A.B. Working on it :)

Comment: @Pilot see the dupe, then you are one of the lucky ones :) ; in many cases, a break is needed. (As a reaction on the comment on the deleted answer)

Comment: Interesting. In Ubuntu there is an option "Disable touchpad while typing" that starts exactly same command. But I never had problems. I have to set delay in syndaemon to 2 sec.

Comment: Thank you Jacob, I can confirm that your command works! Since I have a SSD I used 10 instead of 15.  Thanks a lot, this is such a relief!

Comment: Did you try the checkbox in system settings. It can be used instead.

Comment: @Consumology Perfect, glad it works. I thought I answered a question on a related subject some day, but didn't expect it to be the same answer/question :)

Comment: @Pilot6: Not in normal Ubuntu system settings, at least in 15.04 what you mean was there when I installed "gpointing-device-settings". I guess it is the same setting as in Touchpad-indicator but from what I understand the time delay is hardcoded in Gnome so there is no chance  to use other values but 1 or 2 seconds there. And this is exactly what was killing me.

Comment: Hardcoded is 0.5 sec. And there really is no way to change unless make a custom build. Nut I made so many builds, so that's not a problem. But it needs maintaining.

Comment: Yes, a GUI solution would be perfect for people like me...

Comment: @Jacob: Actually I did not immediately see your answer to my question (you've been too fast ;-) but found your solution from the other post at the same time. I tried that approach first and it also worked of course.

Comment: Could you also please add your original explanation to my question to the other post - I found it most clear but since I accepted my question as a duplicate it is no longer accessible!

Comment: @Consumology Of course! Done. Thanks for suggesting.